# Inserting data of SQLite into MySql Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an ordering app, I am using SQLite to store what the user has added to it's cart. My problem is that how would I be able to upload all the data in the SQLite database to the server.

So for say, when the user presses the ORDER button, it will upload all the data in the SQLite to the databse.

I am doing this so that the person who will be delivering can retrieve and view the order details of the user, but I am just baffled and stuck on how would I be able to approach or do this.

If anyone has any insight or links that could give me an idea, or maybe provide me an alternative approach it would be great. Thanks in advance everybody! :D

**WELL I SOLVED MY PROBLEM** and this is my Solution for anyone who needs it!

```
  Cursor data = db.getCartItems();
        TotalOrderArray = new JSONArray();
        data.moveToFirst();
        while(data.isAfterLast() == false)
        {
            int totalColumn = data.getColumnCount();
            TotalOrderObject = new JSONObject();
            for (int i = 0; i < totalColumn; i++)
            {
                try {
                    TotalOrderObject.put(data.getColumnName(i), data.getString(i));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            TotalOrderArray.put(TotalOrderObject);
            data.moveToNext();
        }
        data.close();
```

it gets all of the data in the SQLite database as JSON and then I just upload it to the server. Thanks to everyone who helped!

Comment: Have u used any HTTP library such as Volley, Retrofit, LoopJ to post data to server?

Comment: SQLite to get data and convert JSON string and passing json parsing. so simple

Comment: @tahsinRupam Yes sir I am using volley.

Comment: @RatilalChopda Oh okay sir, so display the data from the sqlite database and then upload sir?

Comment: So why don't u fetch the data from SQLite database and then store the data to ur MySQL server using Volley ? You can either show the data from local SQLite Database or from server according to ur requirement.

Comment: @tahsinRupam sir would it be possible to do it like this. I have this function in Sqlite which is called **getCartItems** I would get the data from the SQLite databse then proceed to upload the data using volley?

Comment: @tahsinRupam  
So sir if I have multiple data in the database, will I display them in a listview and then retrieve each row to be uploaded to the database and then check if the listview is empty and then it would stop uploading? Is the approach correct sir or wrong? ahah

Comment: It all depends on your requirement. I don't think ur above approach is the most efficient. Exactly in which scenario and time do u want to save the data to the server ? You can put a "Sync" button above ur listView then if the internet is available, send the data to the server. Just an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** Just fetch the data from `SQLite database`.

**Step 2:** Encode this `data` to `JSON` format.
**eg:-**

```
ArrayList<Product_bean > all_product_list = db.getAllProductInCart(cart_id); // here get the products

JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject product;

for(Product_bean bean : all_product_list){  
product = new JSONObject();
product.put("product_id",bean.getP_id());
......
}
jarray.put(product);

jarray is your request jSON.
```

**Step 3:** Send the `JSON` to your `Http...` url.

Comment: So if I have multiple data in the database, will I display them in a listview and then retrieve each row to be uploaded to the database and then check if the listview is empty and then it would stop uploading? Is the approach correct sir or wrong? ahah.

Comment: @GionneLapuz ... First retrieve all data from sqlite of the specific CART.. encode to json and send.. what is the problem. why need list view ? may be, i didn't get your requirement.

Comment: Okay sir got it, Thanks for example sir! :D

Comment: pleasre,... happy coding.

Comment: Sir question, what is the **all** in **for (all product)**?

Comment: @GionneLapuz this is nothing.. its just to clarify. this mean loop on the `List`/`ArrayList` you will get from database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145136/discussion-between-gionne-lapuz-and-srb-bans).

Comment: oh okay sir, so let's for say I have a column which are orderId, OrderName, OrderSize. I will do it like this for each **for(String orderName : orderid) { orderid= new JSONObject();
orderid.put("order_id",data.getString(1));** ?

Comment: aren't you using bean class for the products?

Comment: No sir, I haven't created a class like that, I retrieve it using ,getstring sir. Would it be more easier sir if I did?

Comment: Your edit made it more easier for me to understand thank you sir

Comment: @GionneLapuz yeahh ..ofcourse.. and that's the standard too.

Comment: Anyways sir I have solved my problem and I am glad to say I can restt for now haha. Thanks for all the help sir!